# Fixing Popup Leaflet on the left side

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, leaflet

I need to fix the Popup to the left of the map, but when moving the map, the Popup does not adhere to the left edge

I entered `position: fixed` in styling and everything is fine when zooming, but when moving it breaks
This is my code of Map component:

```js
<MapContainer zoom={this.state.zoom} center={center} zoomControl={false}>
                    <TileLayer
                        attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                        url={"https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"}
                    />


                    {this.state.geoJsonIsVisibleAll[0].geoJsonIsVisible &&
                        <ChuyGeoJsonLayer url="kyrgyzstanPlaces.json" cluster={false}/>
                    }
                    {this.state.geoJsonIsVisibleAll[1].geoJsonIsVisible &&
                        <TalasGeoJsonLayer url="kyrgyzstanPlaces.json" cluster={false}/>
                    }
                    {this.state.geoJsonIsVisibleAll[2].geoJsonIsVisible &&
                        <OshGeoJsonLayer url="kyrgyzstanPlaces.json" cluster={false}/>
                    }
                    {this.state.geoJsonIsVisibleAll[3].geoJsonIsVisible &&
                        <BatkenGeoJsonLayer url="kyrgyzstanPlaces.json" cluster={false}/>
                    }
                    {this.state.geoJsonIsVisibleAll[4].geoJsonIsVisible &&
                        <JalalAbadGeoJsonLayer url="kyrgyzstanPlaces.json" cluster={false}/>
                    }
                    {this.state.geoJsonIsVisibleAll[5].geoJsonIsVisible &&
                        <NarynGeoJsonLayer url="kyrgyzstanPlaces.json" cluster={false}/>
                    }
                    {this.state.geoJsonIsVisibleAll[6].geoJsonIsVisible &&
                        <IssykKolGeoJsonLayer url="kyrgyzstanPlaces.json" cluster={false}/>
                    }
                </MapContainer>
```

And code of popup:

```js
<Marker
    key={f.properties.id}
    position={f.geometry.coordinate.reverse()}
>
<Popup
    maxWidth={250}
    maxHeight={650}
    closeButton={true}
    className={'popup-fixed'}
    autoPan={false}>
    <div className="popup-info">
    <p><span>Название: </span>{f.properties.name}</p>
    <p><span>Местоположение: </span>{f.properties.location}</p>
    <p><span>Описание: </span>{f.properties.description}</p>
    </div>
    </Popup>
    </Marker>
```

Styles:

```css
.leaflet-container {
  height: 70vh;
  width: 60vw;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20%;
  top: 15%;
}

.popup-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 1% !important;
  transform: none !important;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

photo with a problem:
[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It'd be best if you could add your code to a [Code SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/) so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Use modal div instead of popup. You can set inner HTML of that div. If you want to use popup you can create another map pane and add popup to that pane.

```
var pane = map.createPane('fixed', document.getElementById('mapid'));

var popup = L.popup({
    pane: 'fixed', 
    className: 'popup-fixed',
    autoPan: false,
})
```